# Informatica:- How should I duplicate values using informatica

Tags: informatica

```
        I have following data-

        Employee ID Quarter
        1   Q1
        1   Q3
        2   Q3
        3   Q2
        3   Q1
        4   Q4


        and i want to convert  it to folowing-

        Employee ID Quarter
        1   Q1
        1   Q2
        1   Q3
        1   Q4
        2   Q1
        2   Q2
        2   Q3
        2   Q4
        3   Q1
        3   Q2
        3   Q3
        3   Q4
        4   Q1
        4   Q2
        4   Q3
        4   Q4
```

As depicted inn the tables above I want that the data  be multiplied.
Only the data that is not present in the input table must be added in the output table and no duplicate value exists 
Using informatica how can the above table be obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can try:

- Create SQ to read distinct EmployeeIDs and a dummy value 1, like:

  ```
  Employee ID    dummy1
  1              1
  2              1
  ...
  4321           1
  ```
- Createa a dummy source (either file or DB table) having dummy 1 and all quarters:

  ```
  1   Q1
  1   Q2
  1   Q3
  1   Q4
  ```
- Outer Join the two to get list of all Employees and Quarters:

  ```
  Employee ID    Quarter
  1              Q1
  1              Q2
  1              Q3
  1              Q4
  ...
  4321           Q1
  4321           Q2
  4321           Q3
  4321           Q4
  ```
- Finally outer join the above result with the input data you've got on BOTH EmployeeID and Quarter

Comment: But this will create duplicate values. I only want those quarters to be reflected  that are missing from main table.

Comment: Why would it? It will join matching ones, and add missing ones. I'm talking about outer join here, not union.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Mark the answer as correct, so other can quickly find it if they'd be dealing with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Java code, you can easily do it in a Java transformation.

An alternative way can be to create a static file with all the quarters and cross join it with distinct Employee IDs.